# Validate the Response for the Correct Status code inside the Response Body

Tags: citrus-framework

I need a help on validating or fetching the status code from the response body.
The below response I received from the server.

> INBOUND_MESSAGE:
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1 Content-Type:application/json
>   Content-Length:253 Date:Wed, 16 Aug 2017 17:34:21 GMT
>
> {"statusCode":201,"message":"Product added successfully with name :
>   StudentGuide","result":{"id":"5994821d1aee56c4dad4f04a","name":"StudentGuide","description":"StudentsGuide","price":123.0,"forSale":true,"category":"Books"},"errors":null,"others":null}

Is there a way to validate the "statusCode" inside the response body?
I tried all the possible way but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 2):

Citrus provides various methods for message validation, as described in the [Citrus Documentation.](http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/html/index.html#message-validation)

Using [JSONPath validation](http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/html/index.html#validate-with-jsonpath), validation could look like this (using Java DSL):

```
receive(yourEndpoint)
    .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
    .validate("$.statusCode", "201");
```